# Secure Hosting Environment

Tags: php, security, hosting

I want to provide free (website) hosting for some people.
Which are hosted on my own hosting account.

Now, I have a folder called "hosting_ftp".
In that folder, is a folder for every person who wants hosting.
They will get an FTP account which gives them access to that directory (and no other, as that directory is set as their root folder)

But, for example PHP scripts can still access files, which are put in the root folder (my personal website files).

Now what's the best way of preventing users from accessing those files in my root directory (just anywhere else than their own folder).

Comment: Because you said "hosted on my own _hosting_ account": No way. You must change the server configuration.

Comment: Every individual hosting account should be `chroot`'d  to their directory.

Comment: @nickb is that done by setting an FTP account root?

Comment: No, this is done by changing the several configurations of the server

Comment: Are there any other options? Or at least to make it harder?

Comment: Ask your hoster to change the server configuration? But I assume he will tell you, that your friends should create an own account ;)

Comment: php open_basedir is what you are looking for

Comment: @MartinSamson instead of commenting, create an answer next time as I can't rate comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't assure what you want to achieve here, unless you have a VPS or other form of cloud VM for your service.  With this, you could do it the way that shared hosting providers do it, which is to use UID-based access control, with each account having its own UID and potentially (but not necessarily) being chroot isolated.

This type of solution uses suEXEC or suPHP wrapped PHP-CGI for each user, so that PHP runs in the users UID and thus other others can use file protection to prevent read to write to their content by others.

If you are on a shard hosting account, then you only have a single UID.  All sub-accounts will have FTP access to their directory tree and if you've enabled PHP scripting in those directory hierarchies then their PHP scripts will have full R/W access to your entire directory hierarchy.  Your hosting provider won't give you any root privileges.

So if you want to run your own VM, and have a reasonable knowledge of LAMP server admin, then what you suggest is doable.  If you not then you must assume that anyone that you give FTP access to will have full access to everyone's data within your hierarchy.  Sorry.